# About using pcloud API using access token

Tags: android, pcloud

I'm currently studying the pCloud API and have a couple of specific questions regarding its usage:

Use the `userinfo` API with access token and I get an instant correct response.

```
import requests

account_url = "https://api.pcloud.com/userinfo"

access_token ="ACCESS TOKEN"

response = requests.get(account_url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",}) 

account_info = response.json()
print(account_info)
```

However, if I use `listtokens` API instead of `userinfo` API, I receive:

> {'result': 1000, 'error': 'Log in required.'} response.

Is there a way to use the `listtokens` API using an access token?

I know that I can use authentication token as below. (`https://api.pcloud.com/listtokens?auth={Authentication token}`)

I contacted the pcloud support team and was told to only look at docs.pcloud.com

Or is there a way to obtain an authentication token using an access token? (other than using `passworddigest`)

I want to know how to use other APIs such as `listtokens` using access token.
(I want to collect the cloud information of the attacker using the pcloud access token by requesting an API after discovering that the access token is hardcoded in the information leaking malicious application)